# How can I activate syntax highlighting in IntelliJ IDEA for my custom language?

Tags: json, intellij-idea, mapping, schema, intellij-plugin

I have schema files for a custom language, but as it is not recognized by IntelliJ IDEA, it is just plain text, without any syntax highlighting, error detection, etc.
My assignment is to create it, which was meant to be done by creating a plugin to IntelliJ IDEA for custom language support, but I got a tip from a colleague, that this issue could be solved by using JSON mapping.
But I am not sure how I could map my own schema files to JSON schema files.
What I have done so far is, let's say I have this schema file for example, in the custom language:

```
explore example_explore {
    priority 2;
    from ExampleExplore;
    join Dates {
        type cross;
    }
    join Example{
        type inner;
        on ExampleExplore.account_id = Example.account_id;
    }
    join Clients {
        type inner;
        on Example.client_id = Clients.client_id;
    }
    always_filter account_type = AccountType.ExampleAccType;
}
```

Which I translated to JSON:

```
{
  "name": "example_explore",
  "priority": 2,
  "root_view" : "ExampleExplore",
  "joins" : [
    {
      "view": "Dates",
      "type" : "cross"
    },
    {
      "view": "Example",
      "type": "inner",
      "on": "ExampleExplore.account_id = Example.account_id"
    },
    {
      "view": "Clients",
      "type": "inner",
      "on" : "Example.client_id = Clients.client_id"
    }
  ],
  "always_filter" : "account_type = AccountType.ExampleAccType"
}
```

Now if I convert this JSON file to a JSON Schema, and validate it then it works fine, but how do I map the custom file's schema to it?

I tried associating the custom language schema files with JSON, and then validate them with the JSON Schema I made, but it shows error 'JSON standard allows only one top-level value'

Comment: You will need your own plug-in for IntelliJ IDEA to support this language or a TextMate bundle.